# Query with individual dates, counting values by criteria

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2016

I want a query that only shows individual dates (so no single date appears twice/multiple), counts the number of records with given date and counts further the number of records with another field fulfilling other criteria:

```
Date    | total amount | Field2 = "Aaa" | Field2 = "Bbb" | Filed2 = ....
10.7.18 | 32           | 2              | 3              | ...
11.7.18 | 20           | 5              | 2              | ...
```

My approach is a query with its property set to "unique values" to "yes", than I added the date-field two times, first with its function set to "group by", the second with its function set to "count"; this gives me my individual dates only and the number of records with the set date. SO far so good.

Now I add "Field2", set its function to "count", and add the criteria to "=Value("Aaa")". This brings up an empty list of records.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
Select
    [Date],
    Sum(Amount) As TotalAmount,
    Sum(Abs(Field2 = "Aaa")) As CountA,
    Sum(Abs(Field2 = "Bbb")) As CountB,
    Sum(Abs(Field2 = "Ccc")) As CountC
From
    YourTable
Group By
    [Date]
```

If all you need is a total *count*, use:

```
Select
    [Date],
    Count(*) As TotalCount,
    Sum(Abs(Field2 = "Aaa")) As CountA,
    Sum(Abs(Field2 = "Bbb")) As CountB,
    Sum(Abs(Field2 = "Ccc")) As CountC
From
    YourTable
Group By
    [Date]
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, works nearly perfect. "Sum(Amount) As TotalAmount" did not work. I replaced it with "Sum(Abs([Date]=[Date))". Looks ugly but does the job. I never used the SQL-view before but will definitely do so from now on. Again, thanks a lot Gustav!

Comment: OK, thought you had an Amount field. See edited answer, please.